# How can I simplify this Query? I need to compare a temp variable value with a column value of multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to compare a temp variable value with a column value of multiple rows and perform Operations based on that.

```
  | intSeqID    | Value |
 ----------------------------
     1          | 779.40
     2          | 357.38
     3          |  NULL
     4          |  NULL
     5          |  NULL
     6          |  NULL
     7          |  NULL
     8          |  NULL
     9          |  NULL
    10          |  NULL

    DECLARE @tmpRange NUMERIC(5,2)
    SELECT @tmpRange = 636
```

Here I need to compare the value @tmpRange with Value from TABLE and perform operations based on it.

```
      IF((@tmpRange < (select ISNULL(Value,0) from @tableA intSeqID=1)) AND 
      (@tmpRange< (select ISNULL(Value,0) from @tableA where intSeqID=2))) AND 
      (@tmpRange< (select ISNULL(Value,0) from @tableA where intSeqID=3))) AND 
      (@tmpRange< (select ISNULL(Value,0) from @tableA where intSeqID=9))) AND 
      (@tmpRange< (select ISNULL(Value,0) from @tableA where intSeqID=10)))
       BEGIN
       SELECT 'All'
       END 
       ELSE IF ((@tmpRange < (select ISNULL(Value,0) from @tableA intSeqID=1)) AND 
      (@tmpRange< (select ISNULL(Value,0) from @tableA where intSeqID=2))) AND 
      (@tmpRange< (select ISNULL(Value,0) from @tableA where intSeqID=3))) AND 
      (@tmpRange< (select ISNULL(Value,0) from @tableA where intSeqID=9))))
          BEGIN
          SELECT '10'
          END
       END
```

How can i simplify this query to compare values. Or is there any other way to pick the values of multiple rows and compare the same with temp variable.

Comment: `IF (@tmpRange IN SELECT Value FROM @tableA)`

Comment: do you want to compare to specific values or all values?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one fairly simple way to do it:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @tableA as table
(
    intSeqID int identity(1,1),
    Value numeric(5,2)
)

INSERT INTO @tableA VALUES
(779.40),
(357.38),
(256.32),
(NULL)
```

Declare and populate the variable:

```
DECLARE @tmpRange numeric(5, 2) = 636
```

The query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 intSeqId
    FROM @TableA
    WHERE @tmpRange < ISNUll(Value, 0)
    ORDER BY Value 
) 

SELECT  CASE WHEN intSeqId = 
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 intSeqId
                FROM @TableA
                ORDER BY ISNUll(Value, 0) 
            ) THEN 'All'
       ELSE CAST(intSeqId as varchar(3))
       END 
FROM CTE
```

Result: `1`.

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/ARFOL51197)

Comment: `SELECT ISNULL((SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 0), 74)`? Did you just cast nothingness into somethingness? How does that work?

Comment: When my query returns null, it means that `@tmpRange` is bigger than all values in the table. this is why I've used the `isnull`. but now that you've asked your question I see I've misread the initial conditions so I'll have to change my answer accordingly.

Comment: There's a mistake in your answer? I didn't know, I got confused by the fact that SQL can `CAST` zero rows to one row, which was my question actually, by what law SQL thinks that's normal?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure **why** it does it, but the fact is that it does. If you run the query in your first comment you'll get 74. Anyway, I've edited my answer to return the correct answer now.

Answer (score 0):

We can try to refactor your query using aggregations.  We almost get away with no subquery except for just one, which is needed to distinguish the two conditions.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN @tmpRange < Value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 4 AND
    @tmpRange < (SELECT Value FROM @tableA WHEREA intSeqID = 10)
         THEN 'All'
         WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN @tmpRange < Value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 4
         THEN '10'
         ELSE 'NONE' END AS label
FROM @tableA
WHERE intSeqID IN (1, 2, 3, 9)
```

Comment: Tim, if you're interested, you can check my answer for a different take on his requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the biggest record in `Value`, who is also smaller than your variable, correct?

```
--DECLARE @tableA TABLE (intSeqID tinyint, [Value] decimal(5,2))
--INSERT INTO @tableA SELECT 1, 400 UNION SELECT 2, 300 UNION SELECT 3, 200
--DECLARE @tmpRange decimal(5,2) = 250

SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT('', intSeqID) AS intSeqID -- Can't UNION int to varchar.
    FROM @tableA
    WHERE ISNULL([Value], 0) < @tmpRange
    ORDER BY intSeqID ASC
    UNION
    SELECT 'All' AS [?]
) AS T
ORDER BY intSeqID ASC
```